OCR app on mobile so good and more accurate than OCR PC software. Why?
As above, I have tried some Image-to-text apps on mobile as well as software on PC and I wonder what make mobile superior PC at this process ?
What i have done : Search through internet and create post on reddit but upto now I receive no answer that satisfied my concern

This doesn't look like a specific question that admits a specific authoritative answer to me.

What do you mean by superior? How are you comparing the apps? What are you testing? You just mentioned one line in the question, add more details.
